# pure-ftpd floods /var/log/messages

Tags: logs, ftp

My `/var/log/messages` is full of messages like:

```
Jan 29 01:00:02 vm2147 pure-ftpd: (?@::1) [INFO] New connection from ::1
Jan 29 01:00:02 vm2147 pure-ftpd: (?@::1) [INFO] Logout.
Jan 29 01:05:02 vm2147 pure-ftpd: (?@::1) [INFO] New connection from ::1
Jan 29 01:05:02 vm2147 pure-ftpd: (?@::1) [INFO] Logout.
```

These messages are generated every five minutes. What do they mean and is it a problem? How can I prevent them?

My system is `2.6.35.12-90.fc14.x86_64`.

Comment: Could you take a look into your crontab? Maybe something is defined there as a every 5-minute task.

Comment: Thank you, you were exactly right. There was */5 * * * * php -f /var/www/simira/web/pimcore/cli/maintenance.php. I configured that a long time ago. I'll remove it and see if the messages stop. I would like to upload your comment but it seems like I can't :(.

Comment: So I make it an anwser :-P

Comment: rofl, i still need at least 15 reputation for that. When I get it, ill upvote you for sure xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you take a look into your crontab? Maybe something is defined there as a every 5-minute task.

Answer (score 2):

`::1` is the [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) [address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) for localhost, so the connection is coming from your machine itself. Due to the regularity of the connections, this is undoubtedly a crontab that runs every 5 minutes. Look in `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.*/*` and `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/*` for a job that has `*/5` in the first column and looks like it might be making FTP connections.